# Injecting keypresses by modifying lpv data

Tags: c++, directx, hook, keypress

The following code states in a comment that I should "Inject keypresses here by modifying lpv data"; however, I do not understand what "0x80" means.

Since I do not understand what 0x80 represents, I am assuming it is hooking the left arrow key to something in order to be able to use the left arrow key. Once the left arrow key is injected? I assume I can use the now edited left arrow key in a post-message?

Please help and shed some light on this, thanks.

```
    HRESULT HookGetDeviceState(LPVOID *plpvOut, DWORD cbData, LPVOID lpvData)
    {
        ...
        // Inject keypresses here by modifying lpv data.
        keys[DIK_LEFT] = 0x80;
        return hr;
    }
```

Comment: `To fake a key press set the high bit of the key index for as long as you need it down.`

Comment: i don't understand what u mean and what is the relation between what u said and the code I posted?

Comment: Think about it. For `GetAsyncKeyState`, you need to bitwise & it with 0x80 to check if the key is down. This and-ing returns whether or not the high-bit of that key is set. It is the same thing you are doing here except that you are setting it yourself. If it is set, the key is considered down. To release the key, set it to 0. You can find more about hooking `DirectInput` using the exact same code you have above on google easily..